# How to change workgroup on Sharp MX-5001N MFP?

Tags: windows-7, network-shares, scanner, workgroup, multi-function-printer

I am the IT admin for a small business and we're trying to get our Sharp MX-5001N MFP to scan to a network drive on a Windows 7 domain using Small Business Server 2011.

After meticulously configuring the address book settings and adding the printer to the DNS manually, I've come to the conclusion that the workgroup is causing the problem. When I try to scan to the network using the address book entry that I configured, it says "Scanner cannot access shared folder" or something like that. I've double checked all the folders are shared and the user account that I'm scanning from has administrator privileges.

On the scanner itself, I can only see three devices on our network- the ones in the workgroup WORKGROUP. All of our other devices (about 20) are in a workgroup called BUSINESS. I need to add the scanner to the BUSINESS workgroup so that I can scan to the network drive. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Setup the folder with SHARE level EVERYONE to have READ access, and for the actual folder for EVERYONE to have MODIFY NTFS access. Use either `\\servename\sharename\folder` or `\\ServerIpaddress\sharename\folder` when you setup the network location on the Sharp MX device. Try leaving the username and password blank and see if it works. Otherwise use a local account on the server with it having access and the username on the scanner as `ServerIPAddress\username` and the password what you set and try there. Let me know if this works and I'll add as an answer for you to accept if it work.